# check object destroyed and load new scene

Tags: object, unity-game-engine

I am extinguishing fire particles by smoke particles so then I want to check that object is destroyed or not, if object is destroyed then load new scene. 
Here is my script,,,,,, Any suggestions ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class hey : MonoBehaviour {
void Start(){
 GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().emissionRate = 0;
 }
 void Update(){
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1)) {
     GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().Emit (20);
 }
 }
 void OnParticleCollision(GameObject obj)
 {
 Destroy (obj, 2.0f);
 //here i want to check and then load new scene.. 
  //I try that thing, but failed..nothing happen
    if (object.Equals (obj, null)) { 
     Application.LoadLevel (7);
 }
 //also this one, but nothing happens
 if(gameObject.tag=="fire123"==null){
     Application.LoadLevel (7);
        }
    // also this one too, but failed :-(
     void OnDestroy(){
  Application.LoadLevel (7); } }
```

Comment: Did you try without the time in `Destroy`? That might be the problem. It's not destroyed yet when you get to the if. Try making it a coroutine could help (and using a `waitForSeconds`).

Comment: @GunnarB. yeah i dnt think in that way, ok let me try then. Thanks for comment :-)

Comment: @GunnarB. Thank You very much it works for me.. kindly post this into answer tab, I will rate it to helpful.

Comment: class names must have a capital letter, so Hay not hay

Comment: @JoeBlow Wao, What error u just find...? Please be stick to the point, and anyhow I am dry running my code and error isn't about class name,I know how to write name of class(all conventions),, and you just even not read the name correctly.. its Hey not Hay...

Comment: hi @FarhanAli you must change it from hey to Hey, cheers

Comment: hi @JoeBlow Cheers Accepted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem: `Destroy(obj, **2.0f**);`
Because of the delay the item is not destroyed when the if is evaluated.

So either don't use a delay or make `OnParticleCollision` a coroutine and use a `yield return new waitForSeconds` or put the check somewhere else like `Update` or use `OnDestroy` in a script on the particle that gets destroyed.